# How do I prevent Gemini from including my IP address location in its responses?

Tags: llm, text-generation, bard, privacy, gemini

I use Google’s Gemini (formerly known as "Bard") to generate creative works, such as stories. However, I have noticed that Gemini often inserts details from my IP address location into its responses, even when I don’t specify anything about it in my prompts.

I have disabled location access on my browser, but that doesn’t seem to stop Gemini from using my IP address information. Also, this happens even if my Gemini Apps activity setting at https://myactivity.google.com/product/gemini is turned off (not saving activity).

For example, I asked Gemini to write a story based on Little Red Riding Hood. This is what Gemini wrote as a response:

> Red's basket bounced rhythmically on her hip, the scent of freshly baked cookies a comforting fragrance against the unfamiliar humidity. Unlike the oak-lined paths of her usual visits to Grandma, this new route was a labyrinth of towering sugar cane stalks, the leaves whispering secrets in the breeze. Her mother had warned her about venturing off the beaten path, about the dangers lurking in the "[redacted]," the dense wilderness that fringed [redacted] City. But Grandma hadn't felt well, and Red, ever the dutiful granddaughter, couldn't bear the thought of her frail figure alone. […]

As you can see, Gemini added details (the ones I edited to be “[redacted]”) from my IP address location, such as the city name and other details, which I didn’t include in my prompt. It’s as if Gemini assumed that I wanted to include details from my IP address location in my story.

How can I prevent Gemini from doing this? How can I make Gemini write responses without using my IP address information?

Comment: I guess that's Google's way of reminding you "we know where you sleep"!

Comment: One idea is to give it an alternative location to work from. Not sure that would guarantee your location data wouldn't be used, but it might be enough to keep it out of the output. Probably not super reliable...

Comment: @Mentalist "If you have something that you don't want anyone to know, maybe you shouldn't be doing it in the first place."

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt Okay. A flawed argument, but also not on-topic for this particular conversation. Let's try to avoid derailing into a general debate about privacy. We know Google is going to have access to the user's location data. OP is asking how to keep details derived from that out of Gemini's output.

Comment: @Mentalist I was also quoting Google. But mine was an actual quote.

Answer (score 1):

In order to prevent Gemini from accessing your location, you should both turn off *and* delete your Gemini Apps Activity. Visit this site to change your settings: https://myactivity.google.com/product/gemini

Deleting all past chats was necessary for me, because apparently they contained information about my location.

For more information on adjusting Gemini's settings, visit: https://support.google.com/gemini

[image]

Comment: The issue happens even if my Gemini Apps activity setting at https://myactivity.google.com/product/gemini is turned off (not saving activity).

Answer (score 0):

Just add it to your prompt.

> You are a fantasy author. You do not include any information in your
> stories about real people, places or locations. Your stories are
> written to appeal the most general audiences possible and should not
> seek to relate to or be relatable to any one given person. When you
> use any locations, names or descriptions of places, they **must** be
> fictional.

Comment: I assume this prompt will make the AI invent fictional names, but what if they want to have real-life names, just not the user's current location?